# Defining or expanding a radio button group in ABAP screen painter

Tags: radio-button, abap, dynpro

How can I define a radio button group in the graphical ABAP screen painter?

It is easy to paint them but they don't work as a group.

Grouping -> define and grouping -> expand are greyed out

Answer (score 6):

**First way:**

To insert a radio button, click on the radio button symbol on the left, then klick on the canvas on the right to insert a radio button.

Repeat for each button.

Select a button to fill name (the variable name that you defined in your ABAP program) and Text (the label visible to the user)

**Second way:**
Open the dictionary window (blue rectangle with a smaller red rectangle inside)

Type the variable name you used in your program (you may also type a structure name for all fields in that structure)

Klick on get from Program.

Select the line you wish. Mark radio button at the right end of that line. Klick on the ok button.

Click into the canvas where you want to insert the button.

**How to make them work as a group**

Select one radio button with your mouse.

Hold down the left mouse button and drag a rectangle around all radio buttons.

Right klick -> radio button group -> define (or expand if you add something later).

Done

**But defining a group doesn't work, define and expand are greyed out**

This can happen if you don't start freshly and you try to add something later to a screen painter dynpro.

This is why it happens: when you drag your rectangle to select all radio buttons, it is sometimes impossible to avoid other screen elements that are not radio buttons. When this happens, the function you want to use is greyed out.

Instead of dragging a rectangle, you

1. select the first radio button element with the mouse
2. you hold the ctrl key on your keyboard
3. while you are holding the ctrl key, you klick on each remaining radio button exactly once.

After this, all radio buttons are selected, now you can right klick -> radio button group -> define which now is not greyed out.